# split url path on slash "/" with express or node url

Tags: node.js, express

is there any way to split the url path for example "/de/about in two parts using either express or node url, meaning I would like to have path[0] = es path[1] = about

```
// doing it this way I get path[0] = "d" and so on
var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
```

thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the url string using the `split()` method by specifying a delimiter (`/` in your case) and it will return an array.

Example:

```
var str = "/de/about";
var path = str.split("/");
console.log(path); // path = [ '', 'de', 'about' ]
                   // path[1] = 'de', path[2] = 'about'
```

Comment: what if one of the path itself has /s, i.e.: example.com/key/http:/ /google.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split command of a string.
[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)